# Run a script when group policy is applied (not at login or startup)

Tags: powershell, group-policy

How would I go about getting a Powershell script on a set of computers to run periodically throughout the day while the computer is on? (we already use the "at startup" or "at logon" but some of the computers are left on without logins for days. We also can't use a regular Scheduled Task because these scripts report data to a server, and we don't want 300 computers hitting the server all at the same second. We also would like to avoid having the script be left running, with the delays determined by the script, because it sometimes crashes.)

Is there a way to either:

Run a script when the GPO is applied (I think 90-minute intervals after startup, which will be staggered throughout the building)?

Run a script at irregular intervals (eg. every next interval would be between 60-80 min) or at random ranges of times of day (eg. Every day sometime between 1pm and 2pm). I doubt this one is feasible?

I guess one way to do this as a Scheduled Task would be to have a random delay of 0-5 min at the beginning of the script, but then we'd like to avoid that delay when testing or when invoked at startup or login.

Comment: If you scheduled a task to run every 90 minutes, it wouldn't be any different than a group policy trigger. It's still entirely possible that 300 clients could all refresh group policy at the same second. A group policy refresh is client initiated, and there is no coordination with the domain controller to time it on any specific interval.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a way to run a script when the GPO is applied?

Yes. You can create a scheduled task that will trigger when a specific event occurs:

> **On an event**
>
> This trigger causes the task to run when specific event entries are
> added to an event log. You can choose between specifying basic event
> trigger settings or custom event trigger settings. If you choose the
> basic event trigger settings, a single event from a specific event log
> will trigger the task. You choose the event log that contains the
> event, the event publisher name, and specify the event identifier.

Source [Triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841)

The eventID you need for the trigger is probably 8006:

> The Group Policy service reserves event IDs between 8000 and 8007 to indicate a particular type of Group Policy processing completed successfully.
>
> [image]

Source [Troubleshooting Group Policy Using Event Logs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749336)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that Task Scheduler allowed you to have event triggers instead of chronological triggers. Looks like, in addition to having the event ID, you need to specify "Microsoft-Window-GroupPolicy/Operational" as the Log and "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" as the Source.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Group Policy Management Editor, in Computer Configuration/Preferences/Control Panel Settings/Scheduled Tasks, it allows you to create an "Immediate Task", specifically created for running things after a GPO refresh.

[Configure an Immediate Task Item (At least Windows 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851779%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> For computers that are running Windows Server® 2012 or Windows® 8, Immediate Task (At least Windows 7) preference items, ( Immediate Task (Windows Vista and later) preference items if running Windows Server® 2008 R2 or Windows® 7), allow you to create tasks to be run immediately and then removed each time Group Policy refreshes. Immediate Task preference items do not provide a selection of actions or triggers because they always create a task and then delete it after it has run.

The only gotcha was that I had to specify a valid user for it to run as ("NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" in this case), and it worked exactly like I wanted.